# PhP shell_exec python code - how to avoid repetitive initiation of python objects

Tags: php, python, shell-exec

In "webpage1.php":

```
shell_exec("\usr\local\bin\python3.5 code1.py")
```

In "code1.py":

```
import bigClass
obj1 = bigClass() # costs >1 minute to initiate
obj1.dosomething()
```

The problem is that everytime webpage1 is called by a visitor to the website, a bigClass object is initiated from fresh, costing a lot of time.

Is there a way that I have this obj1 initiated beforehand, and the shell_exec simple gets a handle to it and calls its method?

Comment: Well I guess this has nothing to do with PHP, since you only call your Python script over and over again maybe you can cache the initialization of your "bigClass" somehow, that depends what actually is talking so long in your class. If the result is always the same you can also cache the PHP script.

Comment: How do I cache it? pickle obj1? bigClass is a Natural Language Processing module, I guess that's why it takes so long

Comment: I mean it depends on what your "code1.py" script is doing, if the result is always the same you can simply cache it yourself in a file or whatever. There are of course many different caching solution for PHP itself, maybe you can look into that (e.g. PHP result caching).

Comment: Can you show me an example code snippet please?  The bigClass() is always the same but the object does a different thing (segmenting a sentence given by the php user) each time

Comment: Well if the result is different you can't really cache it in PHP, but you didn't say that in your question since you don't even call your script with any arguments. So you might be able to use an object cache in Python from your code1.py script, but that's not easy to answer without more context what is best for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try with Pickling obj1.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is not a solution, because the object is not a global one. Pickle cannot handle local objects. I just have to purchase a more expensive server with more memory I suppose for the big NLP class to initialise quickly!